# How to split String in RDD and retrieve it

Tags: apache-spark

I have a log file which has lines as follows:

```
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: 
...
...
ERROR: Error Repo issue
```

I would like to get the value '*Error Repo issue*' value from the below log.

```
val failures=logs.filter(value=>value.contains("ERROR"))
val filteredValues=failures.map(value=>value.split(": "))
for(i<-filteredValues){
      println(i(1))
}
```

I tried to loop the *filteredValues*,using the `i(1)` and got the values.
Is there a better way to do it?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `filteredValues.foreach(println) ` to print the data. It contains the lists.

Comment: @Shankar Koirala:I specifically want the 2nd part of the error message.the foreach loop will give the entire data which is not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access as below

```
val failures=logs.filter(value=>value.contains("ERROR"))
val filteredValues=failures.map(value=>value.split(": ")(0))

filteredValues.foreach(println)
```

Hope this helps